# Reduce volume of audio file by percentage value using SOX

Tags: sox

I would like to reduce the volume of an audio file by 10% (so that the new volume will be 90% of the original).  How can this be done using SOX?  According to the SOX manual it supports a volume option:

> -v, --volume FACTOR
>
> Adjust volume by a factor of FACTOR. This is a linear (amplitude) adjustment, so a number less than 1 decreases the
>   volume; greater than 1 increases it. If a negative number is given,
>   then in addition to the volume adjustment, the audio signal will be
>   inverted.

Does that mean that the command `sox -v 0.9 audio.wav audio.wav` will give me an audio file at 90% the volume of the original?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It appears to be correct, that

```
sox -v 0.9 in.wav out.wav
```

will give you an audio file with 90% volume of the original.

**stat** will reveal this, when you compare the **Maximum amplitude** and **Minimum amplitude** output values.

```
sox in.wav tmp.wav stat
sox out.wav tmp.wav stat
```

Note, that using the same file for both input and output file will result in a broken file.